# Does the intelligence and wisdom, and therefore character of your familiar change in 5E D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

Whilst I know that this is mostly up to the DM, the Find Familiar spell in 5th edition lets the PC summon a spirit which take the form of your familiar.  You can change form; - and thereby take on the stats of that new form.

I presume that you have a relationship with that spirit/familiar which is going to be very strange if their Intelligence and Wisdom changes.

- Cats, for example have an animal Intelligence of 3 and Wisdom of 12
- Pseudodragons, as can be summoned by Warlocks, have an Intelligence
  of 12 and Wisdom of 10.

  The spell says that if you cast the Find Familiar spell when you already have a familiar, it can take on a different form, ergo it is the same spirit.

Does the spirit's character change?  In which case, is it going to hate going from an Imp (Int:11) to a Rat (Int:2)?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about how much of this *isn't* up to the DM, would that be accurate?

Comment: Welcome to RPG stack exchange! Are you asking if there is rules evidence for the familiar's mental stats being kept between forms?

Comment: @Anagkai, by RAW, then obviously no. I'm wondering if there is anything about them maintaining their personality or the relationship they have with their caster in official documentation. Of course, I know that as DM, it's up to me to play it how I want to, but I'm not finding it an easy concept. I suppose it's the same as a polymorph spell. No polymorph in fiction plays it like that they, they always maintain the same personality, intelligence and wisdom.

Comment: Are you asking: Do ability attributes define the character/personality of a familiar?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

### [Stats](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AbilityScoresandModifiers) do not define personality

> •  **Strength**, measuring physical power
>
> •   **Dexterity**, measuring agility
>
> •   **Constitution**, measuring endurance
>
> •   **Intelligence**, measuring reasoning and memory
>
> •  **Wisdom**, measuring perception and insight
>
> •   **Charisma**, measuring force of personality

Intelligence and Wisdom have as much to do with personality as Strength, Dexterity or Constitution. Charisma only reflects the “force” of that personality. So, your familiar might have more or less of whatever personality they normally have.

Comment: I suppose that's fair.

Comment: "Intelligence, measuring reasoning and memory" so upon changing a pseudodragon into a rat, it gets massive dementia? I haven't made that experience myself, but I'd wager that anyone who had relatives go through something like dementia would tell you that "changing mental stats such as INT or WIS" does indeed alter a person's personality or behaviour (in one way or another). That being said, I think the whole thing is up to the DM and this question is opinion-based by nature.

Comment: @PixelMaster I can’t see where it says that Intelligence measures medical conditions like dementia

Comment: @DaleM I'm not saying low INT = dementia. It's just that if INT influences reasoning and memory, then I imagine going from high to low INT like getting dementia. Either way, in my opinion, your mental capabilities in terms of reasoning and memory are definitely a part of your personality. If I myself suddenly couldn't remember what I did 5 minutes ago or couldn't tell you what 2+2 is, then I most certainly would be a different person in many aspects.

Answer (score 0):

That, like many things, this is entirely up to the DM.  To take your example, though, an Imp can itself take the form of a rat, raven, or spider while keeping its mind and intellect.  So I'd expect that if you dismissed it, and resummoned it in ordinary rat form with a 2 Int, it would be upset with you.  But the DM gets to decide and roleplay all of that.

Comment: What is your source for this answer? Please mind that we require answers [backed-up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-rpg-stack-exchange).

Comment: Would a character with 2 Intelligence even be able to remember that it used to be smarter? Remember that 2 Intelligence is barely more intelligent than someone affectd by *feeblemind* which says "The creature can't cast spells, activate magic items, understand language, or communicate in any intelligible way. The creature can, however, identify its friends, follow them, and even protect them." Losing the ability to communicate entirely seems like a pretty major detriment to memory since that is instinctive memory for most animals of even marginally high intellect.